# Android - Downloading Web Content Error - Skipped X frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to download web content using a multi thread approach. I am following an online android development tutorial service so I know believe my code is correct (The complete android web developer course Chapter 5). However, after displaying part of the web page in the log as requested, I get the message:

"I/Choreographer: Skipped 743 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

I am using the AsynTask but still no luck.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) { /


            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in  = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = task.execute("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Contents of URL", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code compiles? Execute returns itself, not the result type, hence your assignment to result should trigger a compile error. If it would return the result type it would not be asynchronous..

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do call the `AsyncTask.get()` method directly in your `onCreate()` method, then you're kinda cheating, because the code is actually executed in the UI Thread !

You really must not call get(), because this will wait for the result, and thus block the UI Thread (which is precisely what you want to avoid)

I guess you did this because you wanted to have the result in your onCreate() method, but you can't.

Generally, you need to show the result in an UI field (like a TextView). In that case, you should use an `Handler` instance to be able to use its value from the UI Thread again.

---

Corrected code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) { 
           Log.i("Contents of URL", result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) { 


            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in  = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document");

    }
}
```